# Solve polynomial equation in $\mathbb{C}[x]$

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

> Find the polynomials $f,g \in \mathbb{C}[x]$ with complex coefficients such that:
>   $$f(f(x))-g(g(x))=1+i,\\f(g(x))-g(f(x))=1-i$$
>   for all $x\in\mathbb{C}$.

I think I have this problem almost solved but I have doubts about my procedure because I've used facts about polynomials on $\mathbb{R}$ that I'm not sure if are true on $\mathbb{C}$. Also I'm stuck in a point of the solution. So as an answer I would like two things:

- Highlights about flaws in my (possible) solution.
- Ideas on how I could complete it.

Of course I will love to see alternative solutions.

---

My attempt:

Let suppose that $f(x)-g(x)=0$ has a root $\alpha$ then $f(\alpha)=g(\alpha)=\beta$, and
$$f(\beta)-g(\beta)=1+i,\\f(\beta)-g(\beta)=1-i$$
which is a contradiction, so $f(x)-g(x)=C$ with $C$ a constant.

Now upon substitution we have:
$$f(f(x))-f(f(x)-C)+C=1+i,\\f(f(x)-C)-f(f(x))+C=1-i$$
Adding the last two equations: $2C=2\Rightarrow C=1$. Hence we have to find $f(x)$ such that:
$$f(f(x))-f(f(x)-1)=i$$
It's obvious that $f(x)$ cannot be constant so $f(x)=y$ have at least a solution $\forall y\in \mathbb{C}$. Therefore the last equation reduces to:
$$f(x)-f(x-1)=i$$
Now we can write 
$$f(x)=\sum^n_{m=0}(a_m+b_mi)x^m=\sum^n_{m=0}a_mx^m + (\sum^n_{m=0}b_mx^m)i=f_R(x)+f_I(x)i\;\;(a_m,b_m\in\mathbb{R})$$
And the next two equations must be true for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$:
$$\text{Re}(f(x)-f(x-1))=0 \\ \text{Im}(f(x)-f(x-1))=1 $$
Or
$$f_R(x)-f_R(x-1)=0 \\ f_I(x)-f_I(x-1)=1$$
But the first of the last two equations implies that $f_R(x)$ is constant for infinite values of $x$ so it must be constant for all $x$.
And now comes the problem, I'm out of ideas to find  $f_I(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is completely correct, and I will continue from :
$$f(x)-f(x-1)=i$$
This means that :
$$\forall k\in \Bbb N \ \ \ \ \ \ f(k)-f(k-1)=i $$

This implies that:
$$\forall k\in \Bbb N \ \ \ \ \ \ f(k)=ik+f(0) $$

so the equation $f(x)-xi-f(0)=0$ has an infinite number of solutions hence:
$$\forall x\in \Bbb C  \ \ \ \ \ \  f(x)=ix+a $$
with $a\in \Bbb C$ a constant, now return to the equations in the beginning and complete the proof.

Comment: Wow, slap in my face ;) I was really near! Beautiful solution BTW.